# Alternate for BtsMSITask for BizTalk

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-deployment

Is there a way to generate only BizTalk MSI before deploying it to BizTalk Server Console. I found a method mentioned here [BtsMsiTask](http://richardhallgren.com/build-and-generate-msi-for-biztalk-server-using-team-foundation-build-services/)

I want to know can we do with any other method without installing any other component?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do this?  The question suggests you have a mis-understanding about BizTalk Dev/Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a BizTalk MSI from the BizTalk Adminstration Console after deploying from Visual Studio by right clicking the application and selecting Export, MSI.

However if you are talking about automated builds to create MSI, then it is rather a long topic, require other components and not suitable for a Q&A type post.

Comment: The link I have mentioned above, in that there is a tool which directly generates Biz Talk MSI from the DLL's , which can be imported to BizTalk Adminstration Console and then later on import the bindings. This process is faster than the normal procedure as my application is big. So I wanted to know that is there any method where we can use same procedure just not by installing any 3rd party tool.

Comment: Yes, but you asked for one without installing any other component.  So the answer is NO.  Unless you mean BTSTask  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560469.aspx  But that still requires you to deploy first and then export via command line

Comment: Ok Thanks... I was working on a deployment script so wanted to know a faster method than the general deployment steps.

Comment: Have you looked at the BizTalk Deployment Framework?  https://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/